# jspm is not show meaningful error on the browser

Tags: jspm

I'm using jspm, so far it's not showing meaningful error when there was mistake in the code

*package.json*

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.16.19"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "npm:react@^0.14.3",
      "react-dom": "npm:react-dom@^0.14.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  }
}
```

*config.js*

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  ...
});
```

For example if I made some mistake in the code e.g. `import xxx fro 'xxx';` or `class Foo exten Bar {}`, on the browser's console it only shown

[image]

Do I need some extra configurations?, please guide.
Thanks